# Bootstrap center navbar middle

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to center the bootstrap navbar to the center and I managed to do it with

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

The problem is, inline-block increases the height of my navbar. How can I return the navbar to it's original height? or increase the height of the .active i'm using on the unordered list? Thanks

Comment: Please post JSFiddle of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use float:none and display. Try using the center tag for the menu:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: i'm using html5, and it says it's not supported.. any other ideas?

Comment: Try using margin-left: 20%; You will need to fine tune the percent volume to get it centered. See js fiddle link below: https://jsfiddle.net/kdqefc2f/